# Laravel 5.2 - Override vendor function from Middleware

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0

i'm working with a package:

https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel

I would like override a function "**getResourceOwnerId()**" inside https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel/blob/master/src/Authorizer.php

So i need override the function and add new function "**getAccessToken_custom**" to the class, like this:

```
public function getResourceOwnerId()
    {
        $check = $this->getAccessToken_custom();

        if($check != 0){
            return $this->getAccessToken()->getSession()->getOwnerId();
        }else{
            return 0;
        }

    }

    public function getAccessToken_custom(){

        $accessToken = $this->getChecker()->getAccessToken();

        if (is_null($accessToken)) {

            return 0;

        }else{
            return $accessToken;
        }
        //return $accessToken;
    }
```

I'm calling the function from my Middleware like this:

```
use LucaDegasperi\OAuth2Server\Facades\Authorizer;

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Return user ID or return 0
        $user_id = Authorizer::getResourceOwnerId();

        if($user_id == 0){
            return $next($request);
        }else{
            $user=\App\User::find($user_id);
            Auth::login($user);
            return $next($request);
        }

    }
```

Can you help me to know how override function vendor ? so i can return my custom values. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create Authorizer.php in your app folder and put this code

```
namespace app;

class Authorizer extends \LucaDegasperi\OAuth2Server\Authorizer
{
   public static function getResourceOwnerId()
   {
       //your code
   }
}
```

In middleware use your `Authorizer`

```
use app\Authorizer;

public function handle($request, Closure $next){}
```